# How to debug Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables package?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I am trying to debug a problem of performance in the Mobile App Service Server SDK of Azure.
Such SDK comes as a Nuget Package, without any PDB file associated.
I tried to download the source code and compile it by myself, generating the PDB, but when I try to link the PDB from the `Debug|Modules` window I get an error

> A matching symbol file was not found in this folder

Do you know any way how I can put (and hit in debug) a breakpoint in the source code of method `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables.TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecuted()`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you only debugging [your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2017)?

Comment: No, the flag "Enable Just My Code" is unchecked in the Options of my Visual Studio